# Sumar tiempos tipo TIME en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta la cual me retorna tres datos tipo TIME, Siendo el ultimo NuevoTiempo una suma de los dos primeros datos

> SELECT `mvp_tomb`.`mvp_dead_time`,
> SEC_TO_TIME((`mvp_alarm`.`mvp_respawn_start`)*60) AS
> `RespawnMinuteToTime`, ADDTIME(`mvp_tomb`.`mvp_dead_time`,
> SEC_TO_TIME((`mvp_alarm`.`mvp_respawn_start`)*60)) AS NuevoTiempo FROM
> `mvp_tomb` LEFT JOIN `mvp_alarm` ON `mvp_alarm`.`mvp_location` =
> `mvp_tomb`.`mvp_location`

```
>Retorno: MVP_DEAD_TIME = 23:00:00
>RESPAWNMINUTETOTIME = 02:00:00
>NUEVOTIEMPO = 25:00.00 (ESTE ES MI PROBLEMA)
```

Necesito que esa suma entre esos dos time me devuelva un valor mas parecido a esto 01:00:00 por que si tengo una suma de 20:00:00 + 22:00:00 me va a devolver 42:00:00 lo cual no es lo que necesito si no que me devuelve 18:00:00

Alguien tiene una idea si existe alguna función sql que haga esa transformación o suma de manera que me quede bien formateada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto con un combinación de `TIME(TIMESTAMP())` de esta forma:

```
SELECT *,TIME(TIMESTAMP(ADDTIME(t1,t2)))
  FROM (
    SELECT t1,SEC_TO_TIME(t2*60) t2
      FROM tiempo
  ) c1;
```

Para este dataset de prueba con los ejemplos que propones:

```
CREATE TABLE tiempo(
  id_tiempo int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  t1 time,
  t2 int
  );

INSERT INTO tiempo (t1, t2) VALUES
('23:00:00',120),
('20:00:00',1320);
```

Y el resultado que esperas:

> ```
> 1 23:00:00    02:00:00    01:00:00
> 2 20:00:00    22:00:00    18:00:00
> ```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me sirvió perfecto! al final lo deje así SELECT `mvp_tomb`.`mvp_dead_time`,`mvp_alarm`.`mvp_respawn_start`, TIME(TIMESTAMP(ADDTIME(`mvp_tomb`.`mvp_dead_time`,SEC_TO_TIME(`mvp_alarm`.`mvp_respawn_start`*60)))) AS NuevaHora
FROM `mvp_tomb`
LEFT JOIN `mvp_alarm` ON `mvp_alarm`.`mvp_location` = `mvp_tomb`.`mvp_location`  (Aplicando lo que me comentaste en tu respuesta)